# Error using mice() package in R for handling missing data

Tags: r, regression, missing-data, multiple-imputation, mice

I am doing regression with a data with Y as target variable and 16 feature variables. I had two date feature variables which where as factor. I converted them to date format as shown below:

```
X2 <-  as.Date(X2, format="%m/%d/%Y"))
```

I had a lot of missing data in my training as well as validation data set. I was suggested to try out imputation. R had a lot of packages like AMELIA and Mice.I started trying with Mice package but I am getting the below error.

```
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : 'x' must be numeric
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Can anyone help me with this error.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Nikita, you seem to have quite the history of posting *software* and not *statistical* related questions on this SE network. Please remember to take questions like these to the appropriate network.

Comment: Seems like `mice` was expecting numeric data in a column that didn't have numeric data. The imputation method used by `mice` depends on the type of data. Check the class of each of your variables, and double-check the arguments you passed to the function. Make sure that you have coded empty values as NA, preferably with the `is.na()` function to make sure that the class is correct. To troubleshoot, try working with just a few variables at a time. If the problem is in a date column, I agree with the answer provided by @AdamO.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about R software only.

Comment: @Adamo Sorry for posting it in the wrong group. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to approach this problem might be multiple imputation of the missing data, if your data meet the requirements for imputation. The `rms` package in R provides useful tools for imputation and model validation. You might also want to look at the `mice` package for the imputation part of the problem; `rms` can handle objects produced by `mice`. The web page displaying your question now shows links to other related questions, whose answers might also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

`rms` is a good package, however, I am not aware of how the imputation was developed in `rms` and `mice` has had several publications on the topic.

Nikita, to the best of my knowledge, you must have a character variable in these data. If you are trying to impute date... which is generally a VERY bad idea... then you should convert the date to numeric (as the function of a number of days since Jan 1st 1970, the default numeric date conversion), then rerun the imputation.

Again I stress that imputing date is a poor idea.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did convert factor variable to date and them into numeric format and it does work. When I am predicting values I have the missing data in my test set for the date and want to predict for all values irrespective of missing value. That's why I wanted to impute date.